# JavaScript Array.sort() with multible keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Can someone help me with Array.sort()?
I can do sorting on one value (e.g. `return a < b`) but not with more values.
I need this case, when some primary values has the same result.

E.g. array:

```
var data =    [
        {
            "name": "Paolos Pizza", 
            "rating_count": 20,
            "rating_value": 5,
            "price": 7
        },

        {
            "name": "Bella Italia", 
            "rating_count": 55,
            "rating_value": 3,
            "price": 7
        },

        {
            "name": "Mama Mia", 
            "rating_count": 2,
            "rating_value": 5,
            "price": 99
        },

        {
            "name": "Mario's" ,
            "rating_count": 23,
            "rating_value": 6,
            "price": 7
        },

        {
            "name": "Colazione e Roma" ,
            "rating_count": 52,
            "rating_value": 4,
            "price": 7
        }

    ];
```

First I want to sort the Array descending on the key `price`. If some entries have the same price, than I want to sort it ascending depending on `rating_value`. If some entries have the same `price` and the same `rating_value`, than I want to sort ascending on `rating_count`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the comparison parts with [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) `||` and take the difference as result for the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) order callback.

```js
var array = [{ "name": "Paolos Pizza", "rating_count": 20, "rating_value": 5, "price": 7 }, { "name": "Bella Italia", "rating_count": 55, "rating_value": 3, "price": 7 }, { "name": "Mama Mia", "rating_count": 2, "rating_value": 5, "price": 99 }, { "name": "Mario's", "rating_count": 23, "rating_value": 6, "price": 7 }, { "name": "Colazione e Roma", "rating_count": 52, "rating_value": 4, "price": 7 }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.price - a.price ||
        a.rating_value - b.rating_value ||
        a.rating_count - b.rating_count;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    if(a.price != b.price) return a.price < b.price;
    if(a.rating_value != b.rating_value) return a.rating_value < b.rating_value;
    return a.rating_count < b.rating_count;
});
```

You can make sorting direction accordingly..

Comment: Have you tried it ? it's not working